# Changing the value="" attribute of checkbox jquery

Tags: jquery

I've spent almost all day to make this work, but with out a luck
I know there are lots of posts about similar issues here but none of the seems to work for me.

I've this basic checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" id="req" class="form-item" name="seroskir" data-label="request" value="">
```

on submit I want to see if the checkbox is checked or not.

this is my jquery as for now ( this is a part of larger code block that handles the form)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("button#send-it").click(sendForm);
});

function sendForm() {
 if($('#req').prop('checked')){
     $('#req').value = "want it";
  }
 else{
      $('#req').value = "don't want";
  }
}
```

What I basically need is to get the "want it" or "don't want" to the `value=""` so the form handler can send those values to mail.

Comment: $('#req').val("want it");

Comment: `.value` is used on plain DOM elements...but you have a jQuery object so you must use `.val()`

Answer (score 1):

`.val()` is a function that returns the value of an element, but also can take a `string` as an argument to assign the element a given value. You can pass a `string` to assign the value whichever element you want.

```
$('#req').val("whatever you want");
```

You could also simplify your code like:

```
var reqValue = $('#req').prop('checked') ? TRUE:FALSE;
$('#req').val(reqValue);
```

**EDIT**
After giving the question a second read...I believe OP should clarify some things. I've edited my answer such that `#req` is being set to a `boolean`. I did not realize originally that we were trying to set the value of a checkbox. A checkbox value can only be set to true or false.

My second point is that despite this being correct in the sense that it answers OP's question, this snippet of code actually serves no purpose whatsoever. Why would we be checking if the checkbox is checked...only to set it's value to `true`?  I encourage OP to maybe offer some clarity on the question, because as of now I'm not really sure what the intended result is.

***You also don't need the ternary statement either, since the result of `checked` is a boolean.***

Comment: thanks for the answer, I have tried that approach but it is not sending anything to the `value=" "` attribute of the input.

Comment: Ok. So my above answer is the product of me not reading the question in it's entirety. Shame on me. But my question now becomes, what exactly are you attempting to do. Firstly, you can not change the value of a checkbox to anything other than `TRUE` or `FALSE`. Secondly, based on the logic of your program, there is no reason for you to change these from `TRUE` or `FALSE`.